# External CSS File

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to include an external css into my PHP file:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css">
</head>
```

my CSS File:

```
    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;

    margin-top:50px;

}

body {
    font: 20px Montserrat, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.8;

    overflow-y:hidden;

}


.container-fluid {
    background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAWklEQVQoU2P8P5PhPwMDAwNjOgMjiMYFGIlWiM2E1oMvwbZU24vDbUFYN/P/f4Z0RjAfv0J8DgT5AUM3ksnIejEV4jAZa5B8mhkH9gxf+iIsnkEyiWiF2GwHAGuiJAtmjT1hAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
    repeat;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}


p{

}

.btn-success {
    background-color: #85C1E9;
    border:0;
}
.bg-1 { 
    background-color: #1abc9c; /* Green */
    color: #ffffff;
}
.bg-2 { 
    background-color: #474e5d; /* Dark Blue */
    color: #ffffff;
}
.bg-3 { 
    background-color: #ffffff; /* White */
    color: #555555;
}

.navbar {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

col-sm-4:hover {
    color:#85C1E9;
}
.navbar-nav  li a:hover {
    color: #85C1E9 !important;
}

.helper {
    margin:auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.col-sm-4:hover {
    background:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAYAAADEUlfTAAAAJklEQVQYV2OMq7zlw4ADMIIkF7WrbUGX/3+G4f+ASS4MVtuMzcEAiGEnwSwsT0sAAAAASUVORK5CYII=")
        repeat;
}
```

The stylesheet is obviously used, but the plaintext is also seen in the PHP file. If tried adding type or leave it away, href as /css/base.css and without leading /, but somehow I won't get rid of the plain text in my file. Any Idea whats causing it?

[image: Here the error]

The PHP File:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Awesome Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/my.js"></script>

    <script>
        ...
    </script>



<header id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

   ...    

</head>
</header>





<body>
    ..
    </body>
```

**EDIT:**

Found the error, there was a sneaky `include(css/base.css)`

Comment: Post up the rest of your php file

Answer (score 0):

I tried to validate your css using the [W3 Css validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) and it told me there's a parse error in your css. Namely you're closing the `background-image:` with a semicolon while on the line below theres a `repeat;`. This is a syntax error, and I think because it can't parse the css, it's just displayed as plain text.

Comment: changed `.container-fluid {
    background:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAWklEQVQoU2P8P5PhPwMDAwNjOgMjiMYFGIlWiM2E1oMvwbZU24vDbUFYN/P/f4Z0RjAfv0J8DgT5AUM3ksnIejEV4jAZa5B8mhkH9gxf+iIsnkEyiWiF2GwHAGuiJAtmjT1hAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC")
    repeat;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}`

Now according to W3 Css Validator my CSS is valid, still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should know if you want to give styles to `php` output commands, like `echo` or `print` you have to type all of your html codes .
And type your `php` codes middle of `body` tags in `HTML` format . Like this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

<?php
  $text = "Hello World !";
  echo "<p>" . $text . "</p>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

But another problem that your code has is you typed a `header` tag inside `head` tags and close it after `head` closing tag and this will break the `html` programming grammar .